# raise DuplicateTaskIdFound(f"Task id '{key}' has already been added to the DAG")

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

```
def getDate(**kwargs):
    big_query_task = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
        dag = dag,
        task_id='del_data_'+table,
        sql='''
        #standardSQL 
        delete from `{}` where {} between '{}' and '{}'
        '''.format(paramf[table]["a"],paramf[table]["part_col"],start_date,end_date),
        use_legacy_sql=False
    )
    big_query_task.execute(context=kwargs)
    
bq_task_1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='del_data_'+table,
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=getDate,
    dag=dag
    )
```

I am getting below error

```
raise DuplicateTaskIdFound(f"Task id '{key}' has already been added to the DAG")
```

airflow.exceptions.DuplicateTaskIdFound: Task id 'del_data_xx' has already been added to the DAG

Comment: Hi @Uyyan, Could you check this similar [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67696938/airflow-problem-with-creating-dynamic-task-within-taskgroup) and the [github link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19902) ? This might help you.